# How does integration by parts work here

Tags: integration

[image: Question Image]

I want to know how the first term integrates to 0. The question is of Quantum Mechanics, the bounds of integration should be negative infinity to positive infinity. I am wondering how integration by parts leads to 0. Please tell me the intermediate steps.
Thanks again.

Comment: Presumably you are assuming all functions "vanish at infinity"?

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't include this in your post, I presume the hypothesis on $\Psi$ is that it, and all its derivatives, vanish at $\pm\infty$. I will just write derivatives with respect to $x$ with a prime (and use the bar for conjugate rather than $^*$).
$$\int_a^b \bar\Psi{}''(x)\Psi'(x)\,dx = \bar\Psi{}'(x)\Psi'(x)\big|_a^b - \int_a^b \bar\Psi{}'(x)\Psi''(x)\,dx.$$
Letting $a\to -\infty$ and $b\to\infty$, the first term vanishes and we have
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar\Psi{}''(x)\Psi'(x)\,dx = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar\Psi{}'(x)\Psi''(x)\,dx.$$

$$\int_a^b\bar\Psi(x)\Psi'''(x)\,dx = \bar\Psi(x)\Psi''(x)\big|_a^b - \int_a^b \bar\Psi{}'(x)\Psi''(x)\,dx,$$
so, letting $a\to -\infty$ and $b\to\infty$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar\Psi(x)\Psi'''(x)\,dx &= - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar\Psi{}'(x)\Psi''(x)\,dx \\ &=+\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bar\Psi{}''(x)\Psi'(x)\,dx.
\end{align*}
Thus, the integral of the sum of the two terms you indicated in fact is $0$.